# Can the expression "fully booked" be used metaphorically legitimately?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, verbs

I'm an illustrator. Can I say "I'm fully booked" to mean that my schedule is full?

I've always heard the *booked* verb applied to "performative" professions: Models, event planners, singers, etc. Never for pure service and creation-oriented occupations as on-site technical support providers or painters. You book a model. You don't book a writer.

If this expression isn't appropriate, how else could I word that "schedule" sentence without being so passive or mouthful?

Comment: As an alternative, many self-employed would use the word "contracted".  For example, an  IT consultant might say "I'm fully contracted".

Comment: I think anyone can say "I'm fully booked for next week" informally,  even a retiree with a busy schedule with rounds of golf, and canasta card games planned. I think 'fully booked' is more about scheduling by time slot than by profession. If it is more about 'work-load' capacity, you hear people say "I'm committed to other projects for the next three weeks" or 'I have contracts that will require all my time until late August"  - or simply "I'm committed until ..."

Comment: Add that as an answer, @Tom22 :)

Comment: @marcellothearcane ditto from me too! For the sake of curiosity, couldn't a self-employed person simply say they are working full-time until a specified date?

Comment: As @Tom22 said, you've seen 'fully booked' used by people who sell their time in fixed increments. Yes, you can say that you're fully booked if you charge by time. If it's piece-work (paid by results) then you might just say that you're too busy.

Comment: I see. I reckon most people don't use booked for visual artists and similar occupations because they don't associate this type of work to time constrains, but the truth is that industry nowadays is inexorably linked to time. The artwork is rarely the end goal, it's often volume artwork for bigger projects—as concept art for games—and you have production deadlines to obey. May it be full time or freelance, you're effectively hired for a certain amount of time. @Tom22 "Committed" sounds good, it's just what I needed! Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Unless you specify the project "working full-time" usually implies you're in-house. Even if you specify the project, depending on the nature of it, it would still imply you're not a freelancer. Saying I'm working full-time on a game sounds like in-house work, I'm full-time on a book cover, not so much, but it also sounds awkward. I could, of course, be completely wrong there! I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Working full-time is simply '*occupying or using the whole of someone's available working time.*' If all that time is occupied, no matter on what, it can be called 'working full-time'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I'm fully booked." or "I'm booked up." is common usage. A quick look around online suggests that it's common in British English than American but I don't think any of us "Yanks" would be confused or even momentarily surprised to hear it.

Originally, theaters and restaurants were booked and people were just busy but I think we can all be booked up now.

Comment: Yeah, saying you're "booked up" in the US is a common way to say that you have all the work you can handle at the moment.  It doesn't necessarily mean that your schedule is actually filled with appointments/events, but can simply mean that your work-to-relaxation ratio limit has been exceeded.

Comment: Hello, Dave. It would be good to add a couple of examples (using reasonable English) taken from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't metaphorical. Booking is an everyday process where people take slots (for example, a superstore arranging to receive food trucks at a certain hour of the day). That's what booking is: arranging to do a thing at a certain time. It isn't "metaphorical" or "figurative" for you to do that with your own time, even if you are a poet, and not a dirty truck.

Yes, your usage is totally acceptable and also very normal and already exists. If you don't like it, then use your artistic skills to invent a new word, or simply say you are "busy".

Comment: Hello, equin0x80. If you check in etymon, you will see that the accepted first usage of the verb 'book' was indeed connected with entries in literal books. All other broadened senses (recordings online; notional commitments) are metaphorical broadenings.

Comment: Thanks Edwin. However, that hasn't been relevant for 400 or more years, and I assume the poster wanted help with English, and not mediaevalism. Merry Christmas mate.

Comment: And to you. But please take a look at the aims of ELU. J Lawler, in particular, has written copiously on metaphor themes (eg  **time is money**: instantiation 'I spent an hour'), and this is the level at which the metalanguage is normally used on ELU. 'Booking' in this sense may well be considered as 'metaphor: subclass, dead metaphor'.

Comment: Indeed you are technically correct, the best kind of correct! And I withdraw my earlier comment. I still don't think it's useful to OP. But thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As someone who works in Catering services, we use Fully Booked as our time slot : man power has been exceeded for the day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).